# Get entire matched data from both tables using one-to-one relation postgresql laravel 5.2

Tags: postgresql-9.1, laravel-5

I have recently started learning laravel 5.2. I have 2 tables in postgresql DB. Parent table is subscription_master having plan_id as primary key and child table is pricing having id as primary key and plan_id as foreign key. i want to fetch all the rows from parent table and matching foreign key rows from child table. how can i use Eloquent model to get the desired result.